# how to deserialize GZipStream?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter, gzipstream

I am serializing a stream and it is being stored in cloud using REST services.
Serialization part is given below-

```
public void serialize(Object obj, Stream str)
    {
        using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(str, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            if (obj is Stream)//This is executed in my case
            {
                ((Stream)obj).CopyTo(zipStream);
            }
            else
            {
                binarySerializer.serialize(obj, zipStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Argument **obj** is the stream content and **str** is an empty stream which stores serialized stream for further use. If condition is executed in my case since **obj** is a Stream.

here is the **binarySerializer.Serialize()** code -

```
public void serialize(object obj, Stream str)
    {
        if (obj is Stream)
        {
            ((Stream)obj).CopyTo(str);
        }
        else
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(str, obj);
        }
    }
```

This works fine and I am able to download the serialized file(which is displayed as binary file with download option) from cloud using **Restlet Client** chrome extension.

Can anyone help me in writing the **Deserialization** part?
I want the deserialization code with below signature -

```
public T deserialize<T>(Stream str)
    {
      //Code here
    }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You mean you're serializing the **content** of a stream? Because unless you're serializing a memory stream, serializing a stream doesn't make much sense.

Comment: you right. I am trying to serialize the content of a Stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestand you right you can write like so

```
    public T deserialize<T>(Stream str) where T : class, new()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        if (type == typeof(Stream))
        {
            using (var bigStr = new GZipStream(str, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bigStr.CopyTo(outStream);
                return outStream as T;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
            return (T)bin.Deserialize(str);
        }
    }
```

If `T` is a type of `Stream`, we are deserializing `GZipStream` to `Stream`. Other cases we are using a simple BinaryFormatter.

**After notes in the comment**

```
public T Deserialize<T>(Stream str)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        if (type == typeof(Stream))
        {
            using (var bigStr = new GZipStream(str, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bigStr.CopyTo(outStream);
                return (T)(outStream as object);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
            return (T)bin.Deserialize(str);
        }
    }
```

To return result from function we convert from `MemoryStream` type to `object` type first then we can use explicit conversion from `object` type to `T` type.

Comment: Hi Alexcei! thanks for the reply. code looks good except one issue. deserialize() has to implement the interface ISerialize(implemented in JsonSerializer, binarySerializer etc..) in which declaration of deserialize is as - T deserialize<T>(Stream str);
due to this I am getting error. Also if I change the signature in interface it would create problem at the calling line and other implementations. Code for calling deserialize is as - return serializer.deserialize<T>(payload); which is generic for all the requests.

Comment: my serializer class has implemented "ISerializer" interface so using 'where' in the deserialize will force me to modify the signature of "ISerializer" interface as well as other classes which implements "ISerializer" interface. Is there any alternative to that? because I dont want to change the signature of "deserialize" in "ISerializer" interface

Comment: thanks a lot! I am getting an issue when deserializing the stream "unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' to type T(which is like Infrastructure.App.App1.Response)'". any clue?

Comment: @Md.ParwezAkhtar, your version of the serialize function serializes stream to GZipStream. So you cann't deserialize GZipStream to other types except Stream. In the case T is like Infrastructure.App.App1.Response, the deserialize method must executes the else branch and to use BinaryFormatter

Comment: I just used the if condition just to check if it works in my case(thinking type is stream). Sorry abt that..Just now I implemented whole deserialize by copying ur code and guess what? I am getting error "The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are:  " :(

Comment: @Md.ParwezAkhtar, I have a simple example on this code. And I don't have problem. Object are serialized and deserialized success. Give an example of your code

Comment: I get the following exception `Unable to cast object of type "System.IO.MemoryStream" to type "Record"`